# Cakephp: apostrophe in URl and view cache

Tags: caching, cakephp, view, urlencode, apostrophe

I am having a problem with cache if the URL has apostrophe in it.

For example:
www.example.com/controller/action/What's+My+Name

On first load when cache isn't there, it loads fine. However, once the
cache is created, the subsequent load of the page causes PHP syntax
error because in the cache file there is a line:

$controller->here = $this->here = '/controller/action/What's My Name?';

Note the apostrophe isn't escaped and hence the PHP syntax error.

How can I fix this? Is this considered a bug in Cake?

Thanks.

Comment: I would consider generating invalid URLs to be a bug in your code. Spaces aren't valid in html.

Comment: I know you meant in 'urls' instead of in 'html' but you might want to edit your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's `urlencode()` function, encode the component(s) of your URL that may contain non-alphanumeric characters before passing them into `HtmlHelper::link` or what-have-you.

You may also want to consider the larger issue of whether it's a good idea to have non-alphanumerics in your URLs in the first place, whether there's a real need served by doing so.

Comment: I actually have to do all the encoding on the client side with JavaScript. I used encodeURIComponent() and it doesn't encode apostrophe. Escape() does, however, Cakephp still decodes it back to just ' in the cache file...

Answer (score 0):

Back to the original answer - You generate invalid URL's and somehow expect the framework to not break?

Either escape them (urlencode) server side or generate a slug for the url.

Abusing the url like you are doing is flat out going to give  inconsistent results - client side and CakePHP side. This is not an ambiguous case - you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks but I should have made it clear that I do urlencode the URL. I
just didn't show the encoded URL here.

Comment: I think your best bet then is to use a slug behavior that converts spaces, apostrophes etc into hyphens or another url friendly format.